# Unshare with overlayfs results in permission denied with su

Tags: chroot, namespace, container, overlayfs, unshare

I am trying to setup 'rootless' containers by hand, with just `unshare` and
mounting `overlayfs`. Currently, I can unpack a rootfs tarball, setup a `/tmp`
and `/proc` mount, and pivot_root/chroot into it without issue. I can also add
`adduser` and `su` as that new user.

However, when I setup an `overlayfs` mount, where the lower layer is the
unpacked tarball, and the upper layer is a temp directory, repeating the above
steps fails with a permission denied issue when I `su` as the new user. I
suspect it has to do with the newly created user in `adduser` does not have
permissions to read from the overlay filesystem, but I am not sure. I don't see any logs in `demsg` even with setting `/proc/sys/kernel/printk` to `6`

## Reproduction Steps

### What Works (unpacked tarball)

Unshare into a new mount and user namespace in a terminal

```bsh
unshare -pf --user --mount-proc --kill-child /bin/bash
```

In another terminal use `newuidmap` and `newgidmap` for the new process:

```bsh
newuidmap $PID 0 1000 1 1 100000 65536
newgidmap $PID 0 1000 1 1 100000 65536
```

Back to the first terminal, in the namespace, unpack the rootfs, setup the mounts, and chroot into it and create a new user.

```
mkdir rootfs
tar -xvf alpine-minirootfs-3.15.3-x86.tar -C rootfs
mkdir mountpoint
mount --bind rootfs/ mountpoint/
mkdir -p mountpoint/tmp/
mkdir -p mountpoint/proc/
mount -t tmpfs none mountpoint/tmp/
mount -t proc none mountpoint/proc
cd mountpoint/
pivot_root . .
exec chroot . /bin/sh
# Create the new user and su as it
adduser -s /bin/sh -D newuser
# The below command works
su newuser -
```

The above steps work where I am able to `su` as the `newuser`.

### What doesn't work (overlayfs)

Changing the mountpoint to be backed by overlay fs does not work.

Repeating the steps from above to prepare the rootfs.

Unshare into a new mount and user namespace in a terminal.

```
unshare -pf --user --mount-proc --kill-child /bin/bash
```

In another terminal use `newuidmap` and `newgidmap` for the new process:

```
newuidmap $PID 0 1000 1 1 100000 65536
newgidmap $PID 0 1000 1 1 100000 65536
```

Back to the first terminal, in the namespace, unpack the rootfs, setup an overlay mount, chroot into it and create a new user.

```
mkdir rootfs
tar -xvf alpine-minirootfs-3.15.3-x86.tar -C rootfs
mkdir mountpoint
# This is the key difference from above
mount -t overlay none -o lowerdir=$(realpath ./rootfs),upperdir=$(mktemp -d),workdir=$(mktemp -d) $(realpath ./mountpoint)
mkdir -p mountpoint/tmp/
mkdir -p mountpoint/proc
mount -t tmpfs none mountpoint/tmp/
mount -t proc none mountpoint/proc
cd mountpoint/
pivot_root . .
exec chroot . /bin/sh
# Create the new user and su as it
adduser -s /bin/sh -D newuser
# The below command fails with permission denied
su newuser -
#
# su: can't execute '/bin/sh': Permission denied
```

### Environment Info

The above commands were run on Ubuntu Impish with kernel `5.13.0-37-generic`

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions for the upperdir. `mktemp -p` must create a readable & executable directory for your new user; perhaps `stat /` after your pivot root call will show `0700` when it ought to be `0755`.

Try again with `$(umask 0022; mktemp -p)`.